# Desencriptar RSA con llave publica en Swift

Tags: swift, encriptación, rsa

Estoy recibiendo un dato encriptado desde backend en RSA con la llave privada, por lo que necesito desencriptarlo con la llave publica pero siempre que lo intento me da un error y me muestra un -50 que honestamente no se que significa.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
func getKey() -> String {
    
    let encodedKey = "TUlHZk1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRHTkFEQ0JpUUtCZ1FDMGxURVNOeVBRN3lGZGx1Zkh6aFJRQWV5dkhzak5FUmRDajArR2RhT08ybXQwTW5vQk53RURRVmE3a2F4NVQ3ZzdYRjZnSUZqNExPL0luODhSaWMvUXFSWDhvWGxubmhWa2xFbmtxczVTQzYyeXFpK2tQaHRaaFVlQ1lWV25OcVhVODFwbXdIc25wY0g1VTVxa2lXTnVoZXRiL2E3T1Z0ckcwZFRKWmg0dHVRSURBUUFC"
    
    let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedKey)!
    
    let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    //let secKey = (try? PublicKey(base64Encoded: decodedString))!
    
    let secKeyData = Data.init(base64Encoded: decodedString)

    let keyClass = kSecAttrKeyClassPublic

    let attributes: [String:Any] =
        [
            kSecAttrKeyClass as String: keyClass,
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 1024,
        ]

    let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(secKeyData! as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, nil)!
    
    return decodedString
  }

func decryptRsaBase64Encrypted(_ string: String) -> String? {
      if let encrypted = Data(base64Encoded: string, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0)) {
          if let data = RSAUtils.decryptWithRSAPublicKey(encrypted, pubkeyBase64: getKey(), keychainTag: "") {
              var value = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
              return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
          }
      }
      return nil
  }
```

la referencia de RSAUtils.swift es esta:

https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils/blob/master/Swift-RSAUtils/RSAUtils.swift

Comment: Tienes esto en el valor que envías: `"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"`?

Comment: Creo que no porque siempre la estoy poniendo como publica

Comment: Puedes revisar en el código de esa librería están una anotaciones, creo que la estructura del valor que envías no es correcto porque según ese repositorio, debes tener ese encabezado y uno similar al finalizar.